# How to detect ctrl+c in node js and mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js

In my node.js Im using mysql. I keep a global variable for the mysql connection and I want to do the `connection.close()` when I end the server using `ctrl+c` or if the server gets disconnected somehow.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`process.on('SIGINT', function() { });` works on both Windows and *nix and captures the signal that is sent when ctrl+c is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Handle [`'exit'` event](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit) on `process`.

Comment: I put this `process.on('exit', function(code) {
 console.log('About to exit with code:', code);
 connection.end();  
});` and then ran the server, then did `ctrl+c`, and it didn't print anything...